# Crystal Reports- How can I format a text object that wraps to automatically insert text at the beginning of each line?

Tags: text, crystal-reports, word-wrap

Here is an example:

```
CSA.1169-1342, 1169-1342, 1349-1353, 
1349-1353, 1355-1368, 1355-1368, 
1371-2498, 1371-2498, 2501-2661, 
2501-2661, 2665-2691, 2665-2691, 
2693-2893, 2693-2893, 2897-3000, 
2897-3000
```

I need each line to start with the Prefix CSA. Which comes from a different field. I also created this string from two separate fields which independently render 1349 and 1342 and add the - and the commas. The Goal is to be able to keep the object the same width while the text sizes may actually change and allow the field to wrap and include a prefix each time it wraps. Here is another example of the field :

```
CRTX.220-239, 220-239, 241-249, 
241-249, 251-948, 251-948, 
90-218, 90-218, 950-983, 
950-983, 985-1000, 985-1000,
```

What I need is for the result to render the following regardless to when the object wraps:

```
CRTX.220-239, 220-239, 241-249, 
CRTX.241-249, 251-948, 251-948, 
CRTX.90-218, 90-218, 950-983, 
CRTX.950-983, 985-1000, 985-1000,
```

My intent is to have this inserted as a sub report that is linked to a group. The CRTX in the string would be what links the sub-report.

Comment: The text size needs to be able to change? If so, that makes things much more complicated.

Comment: Yes Ryan the size of the text and count of the text can change. and the object needs to have the ability to grow.

Comment: But the font size and type will remain constant?

Comment: Yes you are correct. In the example you may notice that the numbers 220-239 and 985-1000 are not consistent. So, the length can change at any time. Equally the prefix length can change as well or can be null which will affect the size of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not aware of the ability to do this dynamically as you size the field but with the following formula the statement containing mod can be changed, this will provide the output in your question. change to mod 4 = 0 will output four numbers per line etc.... (change the field to can grow)

```
numbervar a;
stringvar prefix := split({yourfeild},".")[1];
stringvar data := split({yourfeild},".")[2];
stringvar array numbers := split(data,",");
numbervar counter := ubound(split(data,","));
stringvar output;
for a := 1 to counter do 
(
if a mod 3 =0 then output := output + trim(numbers[a]) +", " + chr(13) +  prefix +"."
else output := output + trim(numbers[a]) +", "
);
output := prefix + "."+mid(output,1,len(output)-2)
```

Comment: Are you placing this in the detail section or group footer?

Comment: detail section. I just re read your original post and realized the "prefix" comes from a different field so you will have to either modify this formula a bit or replace {yourfield} with {@yourformula} which combines the to fields: {Field1}+"."{field2}

Comment: I also strongly agree with Answer 3, PROTIP, but I didn't see any indication this was anything more than a standalone report.

Comment: CoSpringsGuy, thanks.. I ended up going with the example that was provided by Ryan. It is similar to yours but his worked out best. Now I am going to attempt creating a similar routine that will calculate the proper items as they relate to each line.. I will post my results if I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to decide how many number ranges can fit on a single line while taking into account the minimum and maximum number of characters. Given your example, let's say 3 is the most you want per line. This should be more than enough to get you started.

```
local stringvar sampletext :=
 "CRTX.220-239, 220-239, 241-249, 
 241-249, 251-948, 251-948, 
 90-218, 90-218, 950-983, 
 950-983, 985-1000, 985-1000,";

local stringvar array samplearry := split(sampletext,', '); //split string into elements
local numbervar x;
local stringvar out;

for x := 1 to ubound(samplearry)-1 do //ignore last element in array since it's empty
     (if remainder(x,3)=0 then out:=out + trim(samplearry[x]) + ", " + chr(13) + "CRTX."
      else out:=out + samplearry[x] + ", ");

//trim the line prefix if no elements fall on that line
if remainder(ubound(samplearry)-1,3)=0 then left(out,length(out)-8) else out
```

That formula will transform your string into:

```
CRTX.220-239, 220-239, 241-249, 
CRTX.241-249, 251-948, 251-948, 
CRTX.90-218, 90-218, 950-983, 
CRTX.950-983, 985-1000, 985-1000,
```

Comment: Ryan, this works in theory while I am using the actual sample text as scripted above. However when I add the formula that renders this string, I am not getting the same output... can you explain if you placed this in the footer or group section of the report.

Comment: By the way, I am able to use this to suffice for what is intended. My only issue now is how to trim the last comma when the string ends.

Comment: You'll have to use the formula wherever it is in the report where your string occurs. I don't know enough about your report to be able to answer that... you'll most likely need to do some tweaking to the code to get it the way you want. I can tell you that you can trim the last ", " by using the `left()` function like it appears on the last line of my sample.

Comment: Thanks Ryan... this has been very helpful. My only issue that I have now is that it appears that there is no rhyme or reason that I am at times getting duplicate records:   WBS.12422-12430, 12432-12474, 12476-12495, WBS.12497-12512, 12514-12557, 12560-12771, WBS.12773-12775, 12779-12814, 12816-13006, WBS.13008-14100, 13008-14100  The last group in this example repeats and in some cases it may do such in the very beginning. suggestions?

Comment: Here is what I did to trim the last ","   if Right({@TrimString},1)="," then
left(totext({@TrimString}),len(totext({@TrimString}))-1) else
    {@Modvar}

Comment: By the way, I figured out what was causing the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

PROTIP: Complex requirements like this are best handled in .NET or whatever language you are using. Rather than writing extensive code in Crystal, do it in SQL-Server, C#, or whatever, and pass it to Crystal in the form you want it displayed. Use Crystal only as a presentation service.

You will regret turning .rpts into mini-applications. It binds you to that technology forever and makes support/maintenance difficult.

Comment: Keep in mind that Crystal can be used as a stand-alone reporting tool.

Comment: Fully understood. My point is just that Crystal is not not the best tool for data processing. I have one too many Crystal report "apps" that are difficult to understand, unit test, view changes, etc. due to all the code scattered throughout them. I prefer to do all the data manipulation elsewhere.